# Updating column in SQL with Blank Value

Tags: sql, sql-update

If I need to replace all mentions of `"TOTA"` in a column with nothing would I use the following concept? It seems simple but all the tutorials that I find are not in plain enough English for someone who picked up SQL last week.

```
Update Tablename 
set indcode =case when indcode in('TOTA', then 'blank' else 'leave it alone' End);
```

Comment: please tag the version of RDBMS you are using ..this would also work  ..`update table set indcode='' where indcode='tota'`

Comment: or using a case (just for example...  use a WHERE in this scenario as it makes more sense): `set indcode = CASE WHEN indcode = 'TOTA' THEN NULL ELSE indcode END`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set to null  for assign  blank value

```
Update Tablename 
 set indcode = NULL
 where indcode ='TOTA';
```

and use where for filter the row to update

if you need  a set of value for filter  you can use a IN clause eg

```
 Update Tablename 
 set indcode = NULL
 where indcode in ('TOTA', '0', '000000');
```

or for complex case you can use case when   ..

```
 Update Tablename 
 set indcode = case when 'TOTA' then NULL 
                    when '0' then '000000'
                    else indcode 
                    END
```

Comment: If I needed the indcode to say "000000" and not  "0", how does one specify that?

Comment: In where ?   you need  to update the value where  indcode in ('TOTA', '0', "000000" ) ?  if this is what you need  the answer is already updated

Comment: I edited the last question. I Need to settle down a bit.

Comment: i don't see  change .. what do you mean ? be esplicit

Comment: If I needed the indcode to say "000000" and not "0", how does one specify that?

I followed your code on changing "TOTA" to NULL and then applied to another situation where I need to have it say "000000" instead of "000ALL". The result is that it displays a single zero. How do I get it to display all six zeros?

Comment: Thanks. I should be able to apply the information supplied here to the other necessary operations.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a equal sign and a closing parentheses, and as written you would have updated it to the string blank,  not an empty string, and finally, you need to decide if you want it to be updated to an empty (zero-length) string, or to the built-in database value called null, which represents, in all relational databases, that the value is not known or is unspecified (as opposed to explicitly being an empty or zero-length string.)

To update to an empty (zero-Length) string, write'

```
    Update Tablename 
      set indcode = case when indcode = 'TOTA' then '' 
                         else indcode end;
```

but you really don't need to update the ones to be left alone, so just add a filter (a Where clause) with that predicate expression

```
    Update Tablename 
      set indcode = ''
    Where indcode = 'TOTA'
```

If you really want to update it to Null, and not to an empty string, then first check and make sure that the column indCode is set to allow nulls, and write:

```
    Update Tablename 
      set indcode = Null
    Where indcode = 'TOTA'
```